# INTENT and SETTINGS activity giving Cannot Resolve Contructor error

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

Working on my first Android project and needed to add a settings activity for program settings.    I created a MainActivity with a single button to test the settings activity.

I created the default SettingsActivity from Android Studio (didn't change anything).

Tried calling the Settings Activity via a click on the button from the main activity.   Getting the following error:

```
Cannot Resolve Constructor 'Intent(android.view.View.OnClickListener...
```

The Settings Activity is called ProgramSettingsActivity and is the default code that AndroidStudio creates... for now.    The beginning of it reads...

```
    public class ProgramSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
        private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
        }
     ...
```

The code in the mainActivity is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this,ProgramSettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
```

Not sure where to go from here... I am obviously missing something obvious.

Thanks for any help....

Comment: Thank You!!  The obvious things can often be the hardest to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProgramSettingsActivity.class);`

Inside anonymous class `new Button.OnClickListener(){}` `this` refers to the instance of this class, not its enclosing `MainActivity` class. That's how it happens.